# Backslash '\' in console.log() not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a back slash in `console.log()` and within `<p></p>` but it seems that when the page loads, all back slashes are removed.

**Example JS**

`console.log('\m/ Lets rock. \m/');`

**Result**

`m/ Lets rock. m/`

How can I prevent it from being removed?

**EDIT:** Backslash not forward slash. Running this on node.js with express, within the `<head>` tags of `layout.jade`. Backslash visible in REPL, but not when running on node in the web browser (Chrome & Firefox).

Comment: wait -- this: "\" is a **backslash** and this: "/" is a forward slash.  Which is the one that you're seeing removed?

Comment: Don't you mean that the backslashes `\\` are being removed?

Comment: Its the backslash, sorry got confused

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `m/ Lets rock. m/` is your result, I see forward slashes.

If you mean *backslashes*, escape them to show that the string wants a literal backslash:

```
console.log('\\m/ Lets rock. \\m/');
```

Otherwise, JavaScript interprets this as a `\m`  *EscapeSequence*. That's why you need the `\\` *EscapeSequence*.

---

The solution was that the backslashes needed to be double escaped:

```
console.log('\\\\m/ Lets rock. \\\\m/');
```

...apparently the backslashes are processed as escaped characters twice (once in the initial string creation, then again for some other purpose).

So the string creation gives us:

```
'\\m/ Lets rock. \\m/'
```

...then the subsequent processing results in:

```
'\m/ Lets rock. \m/'
```

Comment: I tried `\\\` and it still does not print out the backslash. Using Chrome

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Works for me in Chrome. I get `\m/ Lets rock. \m/`. This is how strings work in JavaScript. Try again.

Comment: I tried both Chrome and Firefox. I wonder if running this on node.js and express framework removed the backslash..

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Are you using `console.log()` in Node? I just tried, and it works for me using the REPL. Try this: `console.log('\u005Cm/ Lets rock. \u005Cm/');`

Comment: Yup I did `console.log()` in node and all \ were removed. However in REPL it doesn't disappear.

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Strange. Is the string getting any other processing? Are you sending this to the client as HTML? If so, try the HTML character: `&#92;`.

Comment: I used `console.log()` in the `<head>` of `layout.jade`. Nope, its simply a string passed into `console.log`. `&#92;` does not give me / in the web browser

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Sorry, but I don't have a clue at this point. Maybe try `\\\\m/` in case they need to be double escaped.

Comment: Note that typing a raw string in Chrome's console can have different behavior than using `console.log` in Chrome's console. `\m/ Lets rock. \m/` vs. `'\\m/ Lets rock. \\m/'`. Confused me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is the escape character.  You need to escape it.

```
console.log('\\m/ Lets rock. \\m/');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the **back**slash that's being removed, because `\m` is equivalent to `m` in a string literal in JavaScript. You need to escape it, by using another backslash:

```
console.log('\\m/ Lets rock. \\m/');
```

For information on how backslashes behave in string literals, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Using_Special_Characters_in_Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Escape `\` with `\` (this will looks as silly as `\\` in your code)

```
console.log('\\.m/ Javascript logging rocks!!! \\.m/');
```

And add a dot before 'm' for a proper speudo-text rock-hand sign, e.g. `\.m/`, not `\m/`

Comment: I've explained. A bad joke? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslash with a `\` hence you should simply use `\\` instead of `\`.

Answer (score 0):

got to double them up

```
console.log("\\m/ Lets rock. \\m/");
```