# How do you replace a character class pattern with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: `"\W\W\R\"`

I want to use regex to produce this string: `<span>W</span><span>W</span>\R`

Here is my code:

```
"\W\W\R".replace(/\\W/g, "<span>W</span>");
```

Because the pattern "\W" is a character class, none of the escaping I'm trying to do is responding. How should this be written?

Comment: It works see https://regex101.com/r/xE7fG0/2

Comment: It doesn't work on the command line though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` in the string is used to escape the special characters following it, so your string `\W\W\R` is treated as `WWR`.

When run on command line

```
> '\W\W\R'
WWR
```

Double escape the slashes in the string

```js
var str = "\\W\\W\\R".replace(/\\W/g, "<span>W</span>");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor `new RegExp("(\W)|(R$)", "g")` return replacement string from ternary `match === "W" ? "<span>" + match + "</span>" : "\\" + match` within `.replace()` function

```js
var str = "\W\W\R" , res;
res = str.replace(new RegExp("(\W)|(R$)", "g"), function(match) {
  return match === "W" ? "<span>" + match + "</span>" : "\\" + match
});
console.log(res);
document.write(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the regex, it is your string, in string `\` is a escape character, so if you want `\W\W\R` then your string literal should be `"\\W\\W\\R"` SO

```js
var res = "\\W\\W\\R".replace(/\\W/g, "<span>W</span>");
snippet.log(res)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply ensure that the character matched is actually the capital letter 'W' by wrapping it in a square bracket []

```
"\W\W\R".replace(/[W]/g, "<span>W</span>");
```

:)

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. Have you tested it?

Comment: since string `"\W\W\R"` in javascript actually means `"WWR"`, so we can just ignore the backslash ` \ `.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace.