# Replacing all back slashes with forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

In a case, I just wanted to *`replace`* all the *back slashes* with *forward slash*, but while trying to do that I am receiving some weird results.

*Attempt 1:*

```
"\\pest-TS01\Users\pest\Music\musi\New folder".replace(/\\/g, "/")
```

The above line yields the below result

```
"/pest-TS01UserspestMusicmusiNew folder"
```

---

*Attempt 2:*

```
var x = new RegExp("\\", "g");
"\\pest-TS01\Users\pest\Music\musi\New folder".replace(x, "/");
```

And the above code throws the following error,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //: \ at end of
>   pattern(…)

---

*Expected result:*

```
"//pest-TS01/Users/pest/Music/musi/New folder"
```

Can anyone give me a regex that matches the backslashes accurately? Also advise me on How to replace the matched back slashes with forward slashes. And I still believe that the regex that I have framed is correct, But why is it behaving weirdly?

---

*Special note:*

Please do not suggest any solutions using string manipulations like *`split()`* and something similar to that. I am looking for regex answers and need to find a reason why my regex is not working.

Comment: You first expression is OK, your string is not. It must be `"\\\\pest-TS01\\Users\\pest\\Music\\musi\\New folder"`

Comment: Your pattern [`.replace(/\\/g, "/")`](https://regex101.com/r/bZ0bC8/2) works as expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why would you say that? A correct pattern should work for every kind of string... So *your string isn't OK* makes no sense.

Comment: `"\testing\new\string"` contains a tab and a newline

Comment: @mplungjan But if I read that value from a textbox then it is coming as a plain string and my regex is working over that. why is it behaving differently with manually constructed string?

Comment: I don't understand downvotes. It is a valid question.

Comment: You've already got the correct answer from @WiktorStribiżew (& mplungjan). Work with it. Here it is ones more - To have a backslash in a JS string you have to escape it. So  `"\\"` isn't two backslases - it's one that's escaped. Regarding the down votes I agree - there unnecessary.

Comment: @ClasG Why would a backslash is not a double backslash visually when accessing it from a text box?

Comment: Just check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez0qe36s/) and see if you get it.

Comment: PS: I did not vote down - it is however a duplicate - for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace

Comment: This snippet shows what's the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/cp58pmgu

Comment: Use `String.raw()` on your string, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw), convert single `\` to `\\` and finally  `\\` to `/`

```js
string = String.raw`\\pest-TS01\Users\pest\Music\musi\New folder`;
result = string.replace(/\b[\\]{1}\b/g, "/").replace(/\\+/, "/");
document.write(result);
```

---

I honestly don't know what's happening *behind the scenes* with the singles back-slashes, but I guess they're being escaped.