# How to replace all \ char into ' in javascript

Tags: javascript

if, `a = "Bob\'s house"`

how would you replace the backslash with another `'`? 
I want `a` to equal `"Bob''s house"`

I would assume that I can do `a.replace("\", "'")` but this doesn't work

Comment: a.replace("\\", "'") - you need two backslashes

Comment: Press [F12], enter `"Bob\'s house"` into the console and inspect the result - there is no "\" <-- this is an escape character. If you would define `a = "Bob\\'s house"`, then it would work. But this seems somewhat nonsensical to me. How about `a.replace("'", "''")`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as  user2182349 said, `a.repalce("\\", "'")` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because `\'` is treated as a single character. In Javascript `\` is used to initiate an escape character, which means "literally the character after \".

In order to show `\` you therefore need to write `\\`. And if you want to change escaped `'` into `''` what you need to do is simply `a.replace("\'", "\'\'")`;

Answer (score 0):

basically `a = "Bob\'s house"` is interpreted as `"Bob's house"`, youre just escaping the `'`. there is no backslash in the string.

to have your wanted result (`"Bob''s house"`), simply do the following:

```
a.replace("\'", "\'\'")
```