# How to replace backslashes in node string replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, backslash

Simple code, in node v.9.30 i can not replace all occurrences of '\' to get string "n_fdsan__xsa". Should I use different approach?

```
s = 'n\fdsan\\xsa';
r = s.replace(/\\\\/g,  "_");
console.log(r);
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Quentin and @Phillip, I realized that '\f' is different char - form feed and second one is really backslash - '\'.

```
s = 'n\fdsan\\xsa';
r = s.replace(/\\/g,  "_");
console.log(r); 

//   Displays:
n
 dsan_xsa
```

Comment: Log the value of `s` before you try to do anything with it. You only have one backslash in it in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript and backslashes replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the string that is stored is `n\fdsan\\xsa` which equates to `n\\fdsan\\\\xsa` when instantiating the js variable. Once the variable is logged you see the expected `n\fdsan\\xsa`.

In order to replace all instances of a slash character you would use the following:

```js
s = "n\\fdsan\\\\xsa";
console.log(s); // Displays 'n\fdsan\\xsa'
s = s.replace(/\\/g,  "_");
console.log(s); // Displays 'n_fdsan__xsa'
```