# How to replace backslash in string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, replace, backslash

I am trying to parse a string like this

```js
var temp = JSON.parse('{"FHPosition":"consultant","FDesc":"apr4","FHId":"i:0#.w|spdev\gkr"}'.replace("\\","\\\\"))
console.log(temp.FHId)

//expected output: i:0#.w|spdev\gkr
//actual output: i:0#.w|spdevgkr
```

But when I try to replace backslash or do any actions with string backslash vanishes from a string.
Is there any way to replace backslash without it vanishing?

Comment: The fact that your string _literal_ has a backslash in it, does not mean that your actual string has. Try to print it. There is no backslash in it.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2479326), unless the character after the backslash is a valid escape sequence (a list can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672439/)), it will remove the backslash from the string entirely. I believe you need to first use a regular expression in .replace(), and secondly you should stringify the data inside the parse statement before you replace it. Try using this code:

```
var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('{"FHPosition":"consultant","FDesc":"apr4","FHId":"i:0#.w|spdev\gkr"}').replace("\\","\\\\"))
console.log(temp.FHId);
```

Hopefully this helps!