# Adding backslash to string

Tags: javascript

```
var myString = '\\folder\folder1\folder2\folder3\anotherFolder\filname.pdf';
```

The goal is to get

```
myString = '\\\\folder\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\anotherFolder';
```

My first idea was to split on each backslash, do a loop to create the new string.
I got this result for the split

```
myString.split('\\'); ["", "folderolder1older2older3anotherFolderilname.pdf"]
```

Comment: The first string has a single backslash in it - at the beginning. `\f` is just an escaped character `f`.

Comment: There is only on backslash in the string literal. `\f` is a single character. `'\f'.length === 1` and `'\f'.charCodeAt(0)` it returns 12, the Form Feed character: https://unicode-table.com/en/000C/

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = 
String.raw`\\folder\folder1\folder2\folder3\anotherFolder\filname.pdf`;
var mySplit = myString.split('\\');
var result;

for (var i =0; i<(mySplit.length-1);i++){
    result = result +'\\'+mySplit[i];

}

result = result.replace('undefined','\\');
```

Result is

```
"\\\\folder\folder1\folder2\folder3\anotherFolder"
```